# Error "fragment already active" when adding fragment after remove

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have added two buttons to add and remove the fragment with following code.

package com.example.home.appfrag;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
```

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (findViewById(R.id.frame) != null){

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        Button bf1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bf1);
        Button bf3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bf3);
        final Second secondobj = new Second();


        bf1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.add(R.id.frame, secondobj,"hai").commit();
                }
            });

         bf3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("hai"));
                transaction.addToBackStack("hai").commit();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I will suggest to add a tag when you adding a new activity and remove it by tag.. don't use the fragment object to remove it. also when you add fragment, do check if it's exist before add..

Comment: what is tag in here. i don't know what it is?

Comment: i added as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Add fragment with tag. You can use fragment class name as tag.

```
Second secondFragment = new Second();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame, secondFragment,"UNIQUE_FRAGMENT_TAG")
        .addToBackStack("UNIQUE_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
```

Remove fragment using tag.

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("UNIQUE_FRAGMENT_TAG")).commit();
```

Comment: i have added the tag in xml and do add and remove by tag. but it still caught error "fragment already active"  when clicking add twice.

Comment: do you mind sharing the code for the whole activity.. you can remove those methods which is not related to fragments at all...